# How to use rdpmc instruction on AMD (EPYC) processor?

Tags: linux, performance, x86, amd-processor, intel-pmu

This program displays the count of actual CPU core cycles executed by the current core (using the related PMC which I believe is UNHALTED_CORE_CYCLES)

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    unsigned long a, d, c, result;

    c = (1UL<<30)+1;
    __asm__ volatile("rdpmc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : "c" (c));

    result = (a | (d << 32)); 
    printf("Current cycles  : %lu\n", result);

}
```

It works well on Intel processors, but displays a "Segmentation fault" on AMD ones (7001 and 7002). My first guess was to find a new `c` value related to CPU_CLOCKS_UNHALTED AMD event (0x76) without success for the moment

- I didn't do anything special on the Intel side. Does this PMC is enabled by default?
- How can I make it work on AMD?

  - I tried to enable the counter with the wrmsr commands [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56192665/rdpmc-surprising-behavior) but they also gave me a "Segmentation fault" right away
  - I tried the following command `echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/devices/cpu/rdpmc    # enable RDPMC always, not just when a perf event is open`

Comment: You're not in a VM are you?

Comment: No, I use bare-metal servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is wrong, AMD uses different RDPMC values than Intel. Depending on the processor, multiple events are directly supported through `rdpmc`, please refer to this [AMD manual](https://www.amd.com/content/dam/amd/en/documents/processor-tech-docs/programmer-references/24594.pdf) for further information (section `rdpmc`).

The core cycle number should be `0` in your case.

This code works for me to count `PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS`

```c
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static long
perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr *hw_event, pid_t pid,
                int cpu, int group_fd, unsigned long flags) {
    int ret;

    ret = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, hw_event, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags);
    return ret;
}

#define rdpmc(counter, low, high)                \
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdpmc"                 \
                         : "=a"(low), "=d"(high) \
                         : "c"(counter))


int main() {
    unsigned long values1, values2;
    unsigned int fixed0, low, high;
    struct perf_event_attr pe;
    int fd, i;

    //PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS
    // Performance counter 1 on AMD
    // 1 << 30 on Intel
    fixed0 = 1;

    memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS;
    pe.disabled = 1;
    pe.exclude_kernel = 0;
    pe.exclude_hv = 0;
    pe.exclude_idle = 0;

    fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);

        rdpmc(fixed0, low, high);
        values1 = ((unsigned long)high << 32) + (unsigned long)low;
        asm volatile("lfence": : :"memory");        // test ()
        rdpmc(fixed0, low, high);
        values2 = ((unsigned long)high << 32) + (unsigned long)low;
        
        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);
        printf(" %lu\n", values2-values1);
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

Tested on Ryzen 7950X

Comment: You may want to add an ```lfence``` directly in the definition of rdpmc macro to prevent reordering.